# figuring out which site curled out of 3 sites with same curl

Tags: php, curl

I have 3 websites that `curl` to a php script that returns some values

- site1
- site2
- site3
- siteMAIN

How can I distinguish which site curled to main without including it as a variable.

I tried logging `$_SERVER` on site main upon `curl` from site1 but it doesnt include

`HTTP_HOST` or `HTTP_REFERER`

Is there a way i can set it up so it does? Here is my curl

```
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_URL,               $server_url              );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_POST,              0                        );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,       true                   );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,        $postValuesString        );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,        array("Expect:")         );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,       1                        );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_HEADER,            false                        );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    1                        );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,    false                    );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,    false                    );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,           120                      );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,       true                     );
    curl_setopt(    $ch,    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,      CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER only set while redirecting to another URL.

> TRUE to automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it
>   follows a Location: redirect.

FYI: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

So you have to explicitly set the HTTP_REFERER header manually.

Comment: Thank you. You are 100% right.
I added "curl_setopt( $ch,  CURLOPT_REFERER,  'http://www.domain.com/'  "